# mail is not send when the create new user and notify that user

Tags: drupal-7

I have made site using drupal-7 there is the one issue i m facing is that,
When i m create new user i m check the checkbox notify user but the email is not send and message is come like
 Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

i can not understand where the actual problem is

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to send other emails from your site? If not, and if the server where the site is cannot send email from localhost, then maybe you could try configuring an SMTP server via this module: http://drupal.org/project/smtp